# Typescript type with prohibited properties names

Tags: typescript

I need to create a type which excludes certain literal types and accepts every other string. I tried this:

```js
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"

type MyType = {
    [K in Exclude<string,ExcludedKeys>]: any
}

const obj: MyType = {
    a: 0, // No Error
    b: 1 // No Error
}
```

But soon I found out that `Exclude<string,ExcludedKeys>` simply evaluates to `string` and it's not possible to do it this way. Then I have tried this approach:

```js
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"

type MyType<T> = keyof T extends ExcludedKeys ? never : {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]
} 

declare class Obj {
    a: number
    b: number
    c: number // Adding this removes the wanted error.
}

const obj: MyType<Obj> = {
    a: 0, // No Error
    b: 1, // No Error
    c: 3
}
```

but this only works when members of `ExcludedKeys` are the only props of the object.

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QGaMHQ+HI6Bo7H44mzkMgA)

#### What I need

As said, a type that negates those property names assignable to a set of string

```
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"

const obj = {
    a: 0, // Error Here
    b: 1, // Error Here
    c: 3
}
```

#### Edit

Even though I didn't mention it to simplify the context, as [jsejcksn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220113/17607331) pointed out, I needed this type to preserve type info from a given class model. With that said, [lepsch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219876/17607331) remains the accepted one because it does just what I asked for in the most short and simple way. Anyway, I'd like to share how I changed that approach to suit my needs.

```js
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"

type MyType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]
} & {
    [K in ExcludedKeys]?: never
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmE0GkIgM5QC8UARAIYkA+JARiQLABQTokUAsiACrgQA8XAHxEoAbyZRJUANpYoASwB2UANa4A9gDMoXALoAuHbN1MAvlABkYiVNkLl8ZOkw58ugPyHFEAG4QATmZMTBjIZP7QYXgEAPI0AFbWjFJQZJ5QiigAtjQBNpI06Zk5eclSCIZ4wP5KAOZBzIwI6opVUOoJAIyGnDyQfHHxwsTiZZJkhgAMADRQAPRzsP7+6v6pBN6YmPlQNIadswtLK2tkGxBbaDsVpHjqWRDAABZ1DIymQA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```js
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"

type MyType1 = {
    [key: string]: any
} & {
    [K in ExcludedKeys]: never
}

const obj1: MyType1 = {
    a: 0, // Error
    b: 1, // Error
    c: 3, // No Error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, some context:

The code in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219876/438273) will help you avoid assigning values to the excluded keys using only a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables), but you'll lose type information for the other properties:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmE0GkIgM5QC8UARAIYkA+JARiQFD2iRQCyIAKuBAIxFQBvelCgBtANa4AXFDzAATgEsAdgHMAujLLKQ9AL5QAZIOFisUFbESoM2XHk1RlEAG4R5+xggD2yuVG8aACseGXYuSD5iIREyGQAGABooAHoU2Hl5bw8RGhkeZLSMrJyoBBkAZkL0gDlvYuzPekCQgDoyU1SUgD0AfmbgnlaaTrS+gbaEUZ7+lqG0afGi1pWIYARWoA)

```ts
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"

type MyType1 = {
  [key: string]: any
} & {
  [K in ExcludedKeys]: never
}

const obj1: MyType1 = {
  a: 0, // Error
  b: 1, // Error
  c: 3, // No Error
}

obj1.a
   //^? (property) a: never
obj1.b
   //^? (property) b: never
obj1.c
   //^? any (this should be `number`)
obj1.d
   //^? any (oops, this doesn't actually exist)
// ...etc.
```

To prevent the excluded keys **and** preserve type information for the other properties of your value, you can use a [generically-constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmE0GkIgM5QC8UARAIYlQA+pARiQNwBQTAZigHYLACWA9hygIAThDLAIAWRAA1MqmgAeJlCgAVKBDgSOaAgCUICPsLSK8wYTw4BzADRQyHEAD4oAMigAFMsN7zFQ2NTRXhkdEwcfAcOCAA3CGEXFzsmFwAKOPkUCAAudQBKfI0AbxUoUWAUYUEshWYAXxYRMQlpOQV0stUyfIByAAsIJCQ+PocAegAqcoA-crVwaD6LK1s+qB4CDj5gRzw8HhsOMlokaGA+KFBIKD7YhOE+gDp0gCYAZje3gqgpifKtHyAEZJjNVPNVItbvcUABbWiJDZbKA7PZkA5HE5nC5XG7LB5I16fb6-f7lBD5Sw5VINArMJjGDgWKB8WgAKyIQlE4iksmyEC6FKpwhp5TQ-SGIzGqVUeSgb1p9JYbPZzwQ5QmEwAegB+Jiq55oTU6-WGiAmvUGjnPVhQablCFMLzCPiQPwgO6sDZoPgQba7TRwLZ7ATXJZ3EpCfK0Ph8c5OBhQCVQVbWGxJ+UceGI4RJhovd4fD4ATjJAKAA)

```ts
type ExcludedKeys = "a" | "b";

function createMyValue <
  T extends Record<string, any> & Partial<Record<ExcludedKeys, never>>,
>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}

createMyValue({
  a: 'hello', /*
  ~
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322) */
  b: 1, /*
  ~
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322) */
  c: true,
});

const obj = createMyValue({
  c: true,
  d: 'hello',
  e: 2,
});

obj.c
  //^? (property) c: boolean
obj.d
  //^? (property) d: string
obj.e
  //^? (property) e: number
obj.f /*
    ~
Property 'f' does not exist on type '{ c: boolean; d: string; e: number; }'.(2339) */
```

Comment: I replied to this in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73221080/17607331), thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the keys of a type and check if a key `extends` your `ExcludedKeys`. Here's a utility type for this:

```
type ExcludedKeys = 'a' | 'b';

type ExcludeKeys<T extends object, ToExlude> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends ToExlude ? never : any;
};

declare class Obj  {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
};

const obj: ExcludeKeys<Obj, ExcludedKeys> = {
  a: 0, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
  b: 0, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
  c: 0, // works
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the forbidden keys as extra optional properties of type `undefined` to the type:

```
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"


type ExcludeKeysFrom<T extends object, ToExlude extends PropertyKey> = Omit<T, ToExlude> & Partial<Record<ToExlude, undefined>>

declare class Obj  {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
};

// erro as expected
const obj: ExcludeKeysFrom<Obj, ExcludedKeys> = {
  a: 0, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
  b: 0, // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'
  c: 0, // works
};

// ok
const obj2: ExcludeKeysFrom<Obj, ExcludedKeys> = {
  c: 0, // works
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmE0GkIgM5QC8UARAIYkA+JARiQFCOiSyKoY74BiATgPYBbADwAVKBDjAIAOzQE+NAFYQEwADRQRfeO2gSpsggAV+kHqE4A+IlADyAgJbBRGrTvQRrAMihGy5hzIkIQAlFT4eNFFtOF0NFFkIADMHaUxLS0YMZH9oHLwCWyUoKABvehKSsgAuKGkUARoIHgBuCsqaWvrG5rbKqAQuhqbW+gBfNvoAeinxHn4oMgIJSFVMegQ+aTxgKAVFWvhkD048XkEhIsUNI91sXDxrYnKq2oAGDRnNcGgAcm6Rr8oA4CNI+LslngHABzaRkGhIaDAPhQZh-NIAN2av3anSgHygXxEPyg-2G2OBoPBiwKMLhCKRKLRpMx2Pag3xn1mAHcIgBrPDjSZfPh8jZbHZ7JQAJkObBOD3OwiuN3lGHu+CeZXZ7y5UF5PAFQsYiN2aFqND4fERZGkNn20oAdDQgA)

Why optional? So that they don't need to present in the object.
Why `undefined` and not `never`  because `never` is assignable to any other type so if you were to use `never` the resulting object gains all the forbidden properties which you can access and which will be assignable to anything ([ex](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmE0GkIgM5QC8UARAIYkA+JARiQFCOiSyKoY74BiATgPYBbADwAVKBDjAIAOzQE+NAFYQEwADRQRfeO2gSpsggAV+kHqE4A+IlADyAgJbBRGrTvQRrAMigAlFXw8aKLacLoa0hAAbhA8lowYyGQ80El4BLZKUFAA3vTZ2WQAXFDSKAI0sQDc+QU0JWUV1bXZCA3llTw1AL419AD0-eI8-FBkBBKQqpj0CHzSeMBQCool8MgenHi8gkKZihrruti4eNbEeYUlAAwag5rg0ADkjZ1PUA4E0nxL43gOAHNpGQaEhoMA+FBmM9IjEeE9avUoLcoPcRI8oC8OrF3p9Sj8xulAcDQeDIdDMbCcbU2si7kMAO6BADWeHovUY9z4zNm80WyyUACY1mxNqcdsJ9odRRgTvhzrkaTd6VAmTxWey+mClmgSjQ+HwwWRpDYVoKAHQ0VFDWxYD4AM1V0BQeGgVJ4Y1k+JNfDAwAc8zISCAA))

Answer (score 0):

Even though I didn't mention it to simplify the context, as [jsejcksn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73220113/17607331) pointed out, I needed this type to preserve type info from a given class model. With that said, [lepsch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219876/17607331) remains the accepted one because it does just what I asked for in the most short and simple way. Anyway, I'd like to share how I changed that approach to suit my needs.

```js
type ExcludedKeys = "a"|"b"

type MyType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]
} & {
    [K in ExcludedKeys]?: never
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmE0GkIgM5QC8UARAIYkA+JARiQLABQTokUAsiACrgQA8XAHxEoAbyZRJUANpYoASwB2UANa4A9gDMoXALoAuHbN1MAvlABkYiVNkLl8ZOkw58ugPyHFEAG4QATmZMTBjIZP7QYXgEAPI0AFbWjFJQZJ5QiigAtjQBNpI06Zk5eclSCIZ4wP5KAOZBzIwI6opVUOoJAIyGnDyQfHHxwsTiZZJkhgAMADRQAPRzsP7+6v6pBN6YmPlQNIadswtLK2tkGxBbaDsVpHjqWRDAABZ1DIymQA)