# How to define type of object that does not have a specific field, even not set to undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have code like this:

```js
interface BaseType {
    baseField: string;
}

function combine<T extends Object>(base: BaseType, addition: T) {
    if('baseField' in addition)
        throw new Error('addition should not have baseField');
    return {...base, ...addition};
}

const myBase : BaseType = {
    baseField: "xyz"
}

const myAddition = {
    otherField: 123
}

const ret = combine(myBase, myAddition);
// --> ret = { baseField: "xyz", otherField: 123}
console.log(ret);
```

I would like to use TypeScript's type definition capabilities to trigger a IDE/compiler warning/error if `combine()`'s `addition` argument leads to `baseField` getting overridden. With my current setup, I only get info about it when it's already "too late", i.e. during runtime.

I tried solutions as described in answers to questions like [Typescript type with prohibited properties names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73219479/typescript-type-with-prohibited-properties-names). While [solutions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73221080/1560865) are good in many scenarios, they do not work for `addition.baseField = undefined`. As example, this does not trigger any warning:

```js
interface BaseType {
    baseField: string;
}

type RestrictionType = Object & {
    baseField?: never
}

function combine<T extends RestrictionType>(base: BaseType, addition: T) {
    return {...base, ...addition};
}

const myBase : BaseType = {
    baseField: "xyz"
}

const myAddition = {
    otherField: 123,
    baseField: undefined // set baseField explicitly to undefined
}

const ret = combine(myBase, myAddition); // no warning because undefined actually seems to match the "never" type
// --> ret = { baseField: undefined, otherField: 123 } // baseField got overridden
console.log(ret);
```

So how can I specify a type of an object where a field of a specific name must not be set, not even to `undefined`?

Here's a [link to a TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible. TS uses structural equality to check types. You can sort of try to say "I want field `a` but not field `b`" but you can also bypass this. E.g. `type Foo = { a: string }` can have `const x = { a: "hello", b: "world" }` assigned to it if it's indirect: `const y: Foo = x`. Which works because when using `y` the compiler will not let you access `y.b`, even if it's there. A better solution might be to just ignore/override any `baseField` you get. TBH, I'm not sure what the benefit is to have the compiler error, rather than just handling `baseField`

Comment: Your sample code appears to have a mistake - `specialField` versus `baseField` - or maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @JoshKelley - thanks a lot. It had indeed. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, an optional property by default is exactly equal to an `undefined` property; TypeScript's type system simply doesn't distinguish between the two.

TypeScript does offer an option, [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#exact-optional-property-types), that changes this. With that option, your code throws a warning, as desired ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QCoE8AOKA3gFDLnIBGmEAYsBADYAmAXMhmFKAOYDcJAL4kSYAigBKETtwRhgAexB5CyALzIA8pQBWEOcgBkyUhSo16TZgH52ICADdoQkTACuIOYpDIECgLaUoBAAPNjIEAAekCDMGFq6+mAAfAAU1Fjs6FgqEAA0yHDMzMDySuzhxkTmWJYstsj2TlDIggCUJmQUUBBgblA+RAB0Ixn5yCNDRSVlIIICwiR+IJzI-rjZKFk0ueqdZmN1bMgARJG4AF4nLktKq+sAgsWl3numFApgABbQR+wAjAAmADMeS65EODBY7A8zAgMGCzGQAHpkRxejU6FCkVF8IxgAhSoxcMgwApkLD4YibstVj0wHs-IFgql1psCo9nrM2nwUWiQOSAO5wAa8Kj6OBuLAU2JU+xIxB9OCMYnoiD+eJktZwMAIL6kn6nJrQE6k8QkVHIAC0VuSyHpb2Qnx+UD+yCBwNafMxR2QPE+9vVCiczFuKwUjAgQ0YCh4qQAUgBlTQAOSGMl4wBguFS9LabSAA)).

Unfortunately, based on my limited experience, enabling `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` may require pretty invasive code changes.  In my ideal world, TypeScript would let you [opt in to this behavior for specific types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48086). However, this appears to be a fairly niche request.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the hint about `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`. I don't think that the libraries I have to use will play nicely with it, but it's good to know that something like this exists.

Comment: Even exactOptionalPropertyTypes is not a silver bullet. See example: https://tsplay.dev/mM7DZw TS can only analyse the type based on the information about it there is. But information can still be lost through structural equality transformations. Thus if the compiler checks the *type* `{ otherField: number }` it will consider it correct, even if the actual value includes a `baseField`. This can happen quite naturally when using code and just assigning a value to another type. Or more deviously, if deserialising JSON where the compiler *cannot* ensure the type matches.